# How to use Flask-admin with flask-principal(security) to handle users by roles?

Tags: python, flask

I already have custom adminindex with flask-login and I have some `sqlalchemy` modelviews. I just use `is_accessible()` to handle what to show: login form or modelviews.

```
class BaseAdminController(ModelView):
    column_exclude_list = ('created_on','modified_on')
    def is_accessible(self):
        return login.current_user.is_authenticated()
```

For example I have two user types - Moderator and User. How to show some views only for User and all other for Moderator?

Answer (score 1):

---

To make some view accessible for moderator only, you can do something like

```
def is_accessible(self):
    if not login.current_user.is_authenticated():
        return False
    if not is_moderator(login.current_user):
        return False
    return True
```

and then in is_moderator you check that user is of "moderator" type. You did not mention how you store the user type in you data models, so I cannot help you with is_moderator function.

---